# I'm getting a ServerException when I try to send objects from a BlackBerry to a Server via a webservice

Tags: .net, blackberry, web-services, jsr172

I'm trying to send an array of objects wrapped in an array object wrapper to a WS via JSR172 WS calls.  Using the generated stub, I'm able to download objects from the server, but I'm not able to upload objects to the server.  This currently happens on all simulators in house.

This is all the information I can get out of the server exception:

javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: java.rmi.ServerException: Server cannot handle the message because of some temporary condition.

Here are the server specs:

Windows 7
IIS 7 or 7.5
.NET 3.5 for the WS code written in C#.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, or knows where to look, I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that there has been a server error which is specifically on the server.  In our case, it occurred because an exception was thrown inside the .NET webservice we were calling from the BlackBerry client.